# Как написать программу, которая выводит прописью введенное число?

Tags: c++

Как написать программу, которое выводит прописью введенное число? Например, при вводе числа `999` результатом работы программы должна быть строка `девятьсот девяносто девять`

Comment: бьете на разряды в цикле деля на 10 и получая остатки от деления на 10 и для каждой цифры, согласно позиции выдаете из подготовленных заранее массивов со всеми вариантами нужные слова. Конечно придется делать некоторые исключения для значений 11-19

Comment: 999 - это целых три цифры...

Answer (score 0):

Есть вот [пример кода на php](https://habr.com/ru/post/53210/), думаю не составит труда перенести это на с++
Также вот первый из гугла [пример на C++](https://mkonne.org/vyvesti-chislo-propisyu-c.html)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int a;
    cout << "Введите число: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Ваше число: " << " ";

    if (a < 0) {
        cout << "Минусовое число";
    }

    switch (a / 100)
    {
    case 1: cout << "Сто "; break;
    case 2: cout << "Двести "; break;
    case 3: cout << "Триста "; break;
    case 4: cout << "Четыреста "; break;
    case 5: cout << "Пятсот "; break;
    case 6: cout << "Шестьсот "; break;
    case 7: cout << "Семьсот "; break;
    case 8: cout << "Восемьсот "; break;
    case 9: cout << "Девятьсот "; break;
    }

    switch ((a % 100) / 10)
    {
    case 2: cout << "двадцать "; break;
    case 3: cout << "тридцать "; break;
    case 4: cout << "сорок "; break;
    case 5: cout << "пятдесят "; break;
    case 6: cout << "шестьдесят "; break;
    case 7: cout << "Семьдесят "; break;
    case 8: cout << "Восемьдесят "; break;
    case 9: cout << "Девяносто "; break;
    }

    if (a % 100 >= 10 & a % 100 < 20) {
        switch (a % 100) {
        case 10: cout << "десять"; break;
        case 11: cout << "одинадцать"; break;
        case 12: cout << "двенадцать"; break;
        case 13: cout << "тринадцать"; break;
        case 14: cout << "четырнадцать"; break;
        case 15: cout << "пятнадцать"; break;
        case 16: cout << "шестнадцать"; break;
        case 17: cout << "семнадцать"; break;
        case 18: cout << "восемнадцать"; break;
        case 19: cout << "девятнадцать"; break;
        }
    }
    else {
        switch (a % 10)
        {
        case 0: cout << "ноль\n"; break;
        case 1: cout << "один\n"; break;
        case 2: cout << "два\n"; break;
        case 3: cout << "три\n"; break;
        case 4: cout << "четыре"; break;
        case 5: cout << "пять"; break;
        case 6: cout << "шесть"; break;
        case 7: cout << "семь"; break;
        case 8: cout << "восемь"; break;
        case 9: cout << "девять"; break;
        }
    }
    _getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не приводите в поле ответ код по ссылке -- они со временем бывают протухают.